# imread with regexp Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to read an image using `imread` as shown below:

```
img=imread('D:\results\results*.png'));
```

as in the results folder there is only one files that starts with `results` like this for example `results_0.43214.png`. So I'm wondering how I can read this image using the beginning of the file name `results` and without having to write the numbers part. I also want to save the file name in a variable called `name` as I will use it after that, so in my example, `name` will have the value `results_0.43214.png` If anyone could please advise.

Comment: I added the `regex` tag so it can attract attention to people who could likely help I hope that's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `imread` will let you use wild cards but the `dir` command certainly will. You could try something along the lines of:

```
baseDir = 'D:\results';
files = dir(fullfile(baseDir, 'results*.png'));
if length(files) == 1
    img = imread(fullfile(baseDir, files(1).name));
else
    % there was more/less than one file matching pattern   
end
```